# Running another application with Process.Start()

Tags: vb.net, process.start

I'm running application `Test_A` and from this one I'm starting another application called `Test_B` with this code:

```
Test_B.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
Test_B.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
Test_B.StartInfo.FileName = "App_Test_B.exe"
Test_B.Start()
```

In `Test_A` waiting for `Test_B` to exit I'm running this loop:

```
Do Until Test_B.HasExited = True
   Application.DoEvents()
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
Loop
```

My question is, if this `Sleep(100)` will also affect `Test_B` application or only apply to `Test_A`?

Comment: No side-effect on B.  Do favor the Process.Exited event instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test_A` and `Test_B` are both independent processes. What goes on in `Test_A` does not affect `Test_B` unless it explicitly communicates with `Test_B` via some kind of [**Interprocess Communication**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx).

By the way, that loop is not a good way of waiting for the process to end. Instead you should use the [**`Process.Exited` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx) that is raised when the process terminates.

```
Test_B.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
Test_B.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
Test_B.StartInfo.FileName = "App_Test_B.exe"
Test_B.EnableRaisingEvents = True

AddHandler Test_B.Exited, AddressOf TestB_Exited

Test_B.Start()
```

In some other part of your code:

```
Private Sub TestB_Exited(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Do something when Test_B has exited.
End Sub
```

Comment: Great info. Thank you very much.